# I want to run a docker configured project on IIS on local server

Tags: docker, iis, asp.net-core

I have a project build in docker and due to lack of memory(`RAM`) I can't start docker in my machine. Is there any possibility to run this project on IIS on my machine. 

I am using `Windows 10`

 Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other. Enabling Docker support does not in anyway affect your ability to publish directly to IIS.

Comment: Follow [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change docker memory open `settings`

[image: settings]

Then change memory size in advance tab

[image: advance settings]
Then apply.

Hope it will help you. Happy Coding...!